# java.io.EOFException when logstash-1.4.2 elasticsearch_river connect to rabbitmq

Tags: java, elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash

I got EOFException when I use elasticsearch_river as output and try tu connect to rabbitmq.

Here is my config file :

```
input {
    file {
            path => "/tmp/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/log.txt"
    }
}

filter {
}

output {
     elasticsearch_river {
            rabbitmq_host => "hostname"
            rabbitmq_port => 15671
            es_host => "hostname"
            user => "user"
            password => "password"
    }
}
```

This is the stack trace :

```
Exception in thread ">output" java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(com/rabbitmq/client/impl/AMQChannel.java:106)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(com/rabbitmq/client/impl/AMQChannel.java:102)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(com/rabbitmq/client/impl/AMQConnection.java:378)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.java:516)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.java:533)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:606)
    at RUBY.new_connection_impl(/tmp/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.1.2-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:387)
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271)
    at RUBY.converting_rjc_exceptions_to_ruby(/tmp/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.1.2-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:357)
    at RUBY.new_connection_impl(/tmp/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.1.2-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:382)
    at RUBY.initialize(/tmp/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.1.2-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:82)
    at RUBY.connect(/tmp/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.1.2-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:69)
    at RUBY.connect(/tmp/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.1.2-java/lib/march_hare.rb:20)
    at RUBY.connect(/tmp/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/rabbitmq/march_hare.rb:111)
    at RUBY.register(/tmp/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/rabbitmq/march_hare.rb:18)
    at RUBY.prepare_river(/tmp/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch_river.rb:111)
    at RUBY.register(/tmp/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch_river.rb:89)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)
    at RUBY.outputworker(/tmp/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:220)
    at RUBY.start_outputs(/tmp/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:152)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; reason: java.io.EOFException
....
```

Comment: Check if there are any firewall block (port 15671) issue from logstash server to rebbit mq.

Comment: I verify with : telnet server_rabbit_mq 15671. There is not firewall block issue.

Answer (score 0):

use 5672,

"15672 is the port for the HTTP API / web UI.
AMQP uses port 5672."

http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2013-October/030989.html

also don't forget to install the plugin for ES as described in the link below and restart ES.
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-river-rabbitmq/blob/master/README.md